# Importing data into Quip spreadsheet via API

Tags: python, quip

My task is to write some chunks of data into a Quip Spreadsheet and regularly update it using Quip API.

I got the data stored in pandas DataFrame (and can easily convert to any other structure), but the whole issue is around using their API.
I got through painful authorisation process so now it generally works, but I can't find any proper method to update the lines of the spreadsheet.

I tried with:

`client.add_spreadsheet_row(thread_id=thread_id,spreadsheet='Schedule',updates=['Lalala'])`

but it only returns

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iterfind'

Could anyone share their experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, if somebody would need it:

1. you parse the web representation of QUIP doc to extract cells IDs. Use BeautifulSoup for instance
2. Than just iterate through those IDS with

```
client.edit_document(thread_id=thread_id,
                    content = Some_Content,
                    operation=client.REPLACE_SECTION,
                    format='html',
                    section_id=cell_ID)
```